# Should I use WordPress or go custom?

Tags: php, wordpress, crud

I'm taking on a relatively small freelance project and my client would like to update several portions of their site; photo gallery, calendar list, about page, and some event links.

My gut tells me to use something like WordPress and use "Pages" for these sections, but I'm worried about my client maintaining the formatting.  Especially something like calendar dates and links.

They won't be doing any blogging - this is just so they can update those sections when needed (obviously).

But then I thought, what if I just roll my own CRUD for these portions, but I'm not sure if that would be necessary for a project like this.

So what would people out there use in a situation like this? How much control does one have over the formatting of content in WordPress?  I'd like not to have to teach my client on when to call certain CSS classes.

Any help is more than appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Any idea how the top carousel of [BungoBox](http://www.bungobox.com/) was made in WordPress?  Or don't you think it's possible and that is done manually?

Comment: Any more work that has to done is more work that has to be done *AND* maintained.

Comment: i recently created a small page based cms for my brother as he couldn't get used to wordpress but i still wanted to give him access to add pages and update content ect but no access to formatting theme ect. big mistake, he has no idea & when ever he updates content or adds something i have to go back and fix it. unless your client has some knowledge of whatever CMS you use, your find your be fixing stuff. prob best to not give them access and charge a small fee for updating adding content. or make a basic interface to each section of the site that so he can still update.

Comment: Use WordPress, but write a custom plugin for the calendar so you can have structured data / formatting. (That's what I did.)

Comment: Don't roll your own on a small project. Leverage something popular and well-documented. Have you seen http://www.squarespace.com/?

Comment: My client rarely uses the web, but wants a presence there.  I thought about just saying no, and just let me update it, but I think giving them the option to do so would mean more business later.

I think I need to see how the content is written to the page to see if I can manipulate the output so it formats properly; especially with a 3x3 photo gallery.

Answer (score 2):

I would stick to wordpress or similar CMS system. It will be a pain-in-the-arse, to take care of formatting (WYSIWYG for client), take care of security, make the administation pages  nice and functional, and so on.

You will find a LOT of information on wordpress as a cms on the web, for example see [here](http://www.noupe.com/wordpress/powerful-cms-using-wordpress.html)

Have you considered any other cms system?

Comment: there are plenty of WYSIWYG widgets... a full CMS will take awhile to build though. but you have to compare that against how long it will take your to customize wordpress

Comment: Hi -
Good point.  The whole site will be under six pages, so I think WordPress will be good enough for my client.

Answer (score 2):

From the description this is a site that would consist of just a few pages that the client would want to update? if so, I'd stick with wordpress myself. There's a ton of pre-written modules and themes already out there, and there's no sense "re-inventing the wheel". Also I've found in my travels that Wordpress leads the pack in being able to manipulate content to your will of all the CMS's and the available WYSIWIG plugins they have. Remember, if they cant' get their document to look just right, guess whose getting the call, and who will be expected to fix it on your dime if you didn't specify that in your contract (you are offering maintenance as an additional feature right?)

Now if the client is looking for a more robust system, a larger site then I interpreted in your writeup, then I'd look into more of a CMS system such as Drupal or Joomla. Avoid the trap that seems to nail PHP coders that it'd be faster to do it yourself; it'd have to be a lot of custom functioanlity to start looking at building it yourself from the ground up (and even then, there's enough frameworks to help)

Comment: Correct, this will be about six pages so that's why I originally thought of writing my own CRUD, but I can see that getting bigger and out of hand over time.  I'd rather have WordPress' ability in place for them for any future needs.

Yes, maintenance is an additional feature :)  

I just need to see how the content gets spit out on Pages to see how I can work with it.

I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)? Never used it personally, but I think it's built for this sort of thing, whereas WordPress is kind of tailored towards blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Definatly go with wordpress, drupal is just  too heavy for the job and will take you much longer to configure.

If you are worried about your client ruining design with a WYSIWYG editor, just don't give them access.. keep them on a need to know basis for their own good.

Working with wordpress will free you from maintaining security issues and many other unpredictable-at-this-point cases of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hi Rotem,
That is my biggest concern is them totally nuking the site, but right now (as I posted earlier) I don't know how the content will be presented on the page, so if I can make my own calls and display the text properly I'd feel more comfortable.

I will give them Admin right, but I'll tell them what NOT to touch.

There will be a photo gallery, 4 groups of 3x3, so I don't know how I'm going to accomplish that right now either.  I need to do some testing.